# What is by default if we do not declare variable type in Python?

Tags: python

In java, c, c++ so fort we declare data type along with variable name such as int, string, float, double etc. However, in python if we don't declare any data type what it is in by default?

Example:
Java   int num = 1;
num=None
what is by default in num?

Comment: Rhetorical question: How do you create a variable in Python without also assigning a value to it?

Comment: If you write `num = None` then it's None. If you don't set it to anything then it isn't anything.

Comment: You could figure this out on your own. `print(type(varName))`

Comment: This question is a bit irrelevant because you simply ***can't*** declare variable types in Python... You can type hint, but that is not enforced in the compiler-level like C or Java... Python is dynamically typed, which means the type of the variable is simply according to its value. Do `a = 5` and `a` is an int. The next line do `a = "hello"` it will now be a string. As opposed to static typed languages like C where you do `int a;` and `a` can only ever be an int

Comment: Okay thanks. But I am a beginner at pyathon therefore I am bit of confused about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define any variable without initializing it.

So in python:

```
a = 1 # Type INT
a = 'abc' # Type STR
a = None # Type NoneType
```

The type of data that you initialized to the variable becomes the datatype of the variable

Answer (score 0):

In Python you don't asign a type to a variable in Python because the language itself determinates the type of the variable. And it can change in type of execution. For example you can do:

This is called dynamic type, you can read more here:
https://realpython.com/lessons/dynamic-vs-static/

You can try this:

```
x = 3              #type int
print(type(x))
x = 'hello'        #type str
print(type(x))
```

And it doesn't gives you any error.